# I want to be able to select a list of deities based on a character class and their alignment

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am trying to create a character sheet for D & D but want to be able to pass the values of two drop down boxes into a query (service class) that then adds data to another option list. I've tried numerous ways of posting the data but all I get are empty strings. I am using the MVC approach because that is what we have been using at the college I teach at.

There is no issue getting the list from the database purely using the GET method but I can't get my head around how to get the actual data from the form without using a button. The actual query isn't a problem either once the values are in place. I've found a lot of solutions using PHP but this isn't something we're using.

**HTML**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D&D 3.5 Character Sheet</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

        <script src="/client/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/character.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#ffe4c4" onload="pageLoad()">

    <form id="characterBasicsForm">

        <h1 align="center" style="color: peru; font-size: 75px">Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 Character Sheet</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="basic">

                    <div class="cn">
                        <input id="characterName" class="largest character-input-basics" type="text" required>
                        <small>Character name</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pn">
                        <input id="playerName" class="largest character-input-basics" type="text">
                        <small>Player name</small>
                    </div>

                    <div id="cl" class="cl">

                    </div>

                    <div class="level">
                        <input id="characterLevel" class="medium character-input-basics" type="number" required>
                        <small>Level</small>
                    </div>

                    <div id="race" class="race">

                    </div>

                    <div id="alignment" class="al" onchange="test()">

                    </div>
                    <div id="deity" class="de">
    >
                    </div>

                    <div class="size">
                        <select id="characterSize" class="small character-select-basics">
                            <option value="small">Small</option>
                            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                            <option value="large">large</option>
                        </select>
                        <small>Size</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="age">
                        <input id="characterAge" type="text" class="small character-input-basics">
                        <small>Age</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="gender">
                        <select id="characterGender" class="small character-select-basics">
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        <small>Gender</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="height">
                        <input id="characterHeight" type="text" class="small character-input-basics">
                        <small>Height</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="weight">
                        <input id="characterWeight" type="text" class="small character-input-basics">
                        <small>Weight</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="eyes">
                        <input id="characterEyes" type="text" class="small character-input-basics">
                        <small>Eyes</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="hair">
                        <input id="characterHair" type="text" class="small character-input-basics">
                        <small>Hair</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skin">
                        <input id="characterSkin" type="text" class="small character-input-basics">
                        <small>Skin</small>
                    </div>


            </div>
            <div class="ability" id="abilities">
                ABILITIES
            </div>

            <div class="content1">
                COLUMN 1
            </div>
            <div class="content2">
                COLUMN 2
            </div>
            <div class="attack">
                ATTACK STATS
            </div>
            <div class="skill" id="skills">
                SKILLS
            </div>


        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Save Character">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```js
function populateDeity(){
    let formData = {'alignment': $('option[name=alignment]').val(), 'characterClass': $('option[name=characterClass]').val()};
    alert(formData.toString());
    $.ajax({
            url: '/character/deity/list',
            type: 'GET',
            success: deityList => {

        let deityHTML = `<select id="deity" class="medium character-select-basics">`;
        for (let deity of deityList) {
            deityHTML += `<option value = "${deity.deity}">${deity.deity}</option>`;
        }
        deityHTML += `</select>`;
        deityHTML += `<small>Deity</small>`;
        alert(deityHTML);
        $('#deity').html(deityHTML);
    }
        })

}
```

**Java - Controller Class**

```
@GET
@Path("/deity/list")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getDeities() {
    String status = CharacterService.selectAllDeityInto(Deity.deityList);
    Console.log(status);
    if (status.equals("OK")) {
        JSONArray deityList = new JSONArray();
        for (Deity d : Deity.deityList) {
            deityList.add(d.toJSON());
        }
        return deityList.toString();
    } else {

        System.out.println("An error occurred! " + status);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A GET request doesn't receive form data. Add them as URL parameters and in the Java code use @PathParam to read them.

```
@GET
@Path("/deity/list")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getDeities(@PathParam("alignment") final String alignment, @PathParam("characterClass") final String characterClass) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What if I want to use POST instead. I've reverted back to GET because that worked in terms of getting the data from the table.

Comment: It should be GET because you are reading data. POST is creating data according to RESTful.
But if you do want to use POST, then you have to set the formData in the body of the ajax request. On the server side you create a bean that is the same structure of what's sent by the request, then you use that as the parameter:
    public String getDeities(YourBodyBean yourBodyBean) { ... }
It will be populated with the request's body.